# To imcrop non-textual PDF for Mathematica?

Tags: matlab, pdf, image-processing, wolfram-mathematica

I want to prepare one selection of data from my high-quality PDF document which has no textual elements (just a plot), prepared originally by Matlab.
I do not want to give the whole picture for my collegues because it is too overwhelming.

## #1 Tools in Matlab

I know this thread [How can I read an image file that is stored in PDF format (much like reading a jpeg file with I = imread('image.jpg')?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/217873-how-can-i-read-an-image-file-that-is-stored-in-pdf-format-much-like-reading-a-jpeg-file-with-i-im) but I have got denying experiences from my colleagues and to my task PDF should be enough because my data is just a high-quality plot without textual elements.
Most relevant thread is this one [How to extract data from pdf file in matlab?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/155500-how-to-extract-data-from-pdf-file-in-matlab)
Most attempts are based on extracting PDF to TXT, like [How to Read PDF file in Matlab?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/151092-how-to-read-pdf-file-in-matlab) about *pdftotext*.

I want now `imcrop` the PDF such that the output could be used in the time-series analysis of Mathematica [here](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/timeseries/), but I did not find that the default `imcrop` tool of Matlab is supporting PDF, [Crop an Image](http://se.mathworks.com/help/images/cropping-an-image.html).
Some findings

- `Show` and `Save as PDF` based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092253/54964). I do `pdf = Import[filename.pdf]; Show[pdf[[1]], PlotRange -> {{50, 200}, {100, 300}}]` and I see a good selected picture in Image viewer, but failure when exporting the picture back to Mathematica seeing the complete picture. **Why?** `PlotRange` does not crop but only put a white mask on the top of the picture which can separated etc in Mathematica.
- Going from `Show` to [ImageCrop](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCrop.html) based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092253/54964). Wrong approach, confusion with `ImageTake`.
- Going from `Show` to `ImageTake` based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092253/54964).
  The `Show` and `ImageTake` are not injective to each other because `ImageTake` has at least reversed order of parameters `{ymin,ymax}, {xmin,xmax}` according to the manual. However, I could not manage to select the correct selection by just reversing the parameters. **Why?**

### Comments for Mathematica

It would be nice if the regions selected would correspond to each other.
Therefore, I would like to have some visual tool to select appropriate area from the figure.
I notice there occurs some aliasing when enlarging the original image.
It would be nice to know how Mathematica handles such cases with `ImageTake`.

---

How can you prepare imcrop of PDF image for the time-series toolbox of Mathematica?
I think this question is about image extraction.
However, I extended the question to the thread [Better Colormap of Matlab and Image Extraction for Time-Series Toolbox of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101256/9815) for Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica will import your pdf as a graphic object which you can 'crop' using plotrange.

```
pdf = Import[filename.pdf];
Show[pdf[[1]], PlotRange -> {{50, 200}, {100, 300}}]
```

note the values are `{{xmin,xmax},{ymin,ymax}}` in "points"

You can also rasterize and then use `ImageTake`

```
ImageTake[Rasterize[pdf[[1]]], {10, 100}, {20, 100}]
```

here the values are  `{ymin,ymax} , {xmin,xmax}` (note the reverse order )

Note the `[[1]]` here is effectively the page number. I'm pretty sure `Import` returns a list of pages even if the `pdf` is a single page.

If you want to actually extract plot data that's a whole other question. For that I'd suggest mathematica.stackexchange.com and provide an example file.

Comment: `Import` is failing to read the file at all. If you take the semicolon off the first line you should expect to see the page.  Could be a file path issue for example

Comment: oops, should have been `ImageTake`. The numbers are pixel values which in turn depend on the resolution of the raster image.  The values given to `PlotRange` are "points" (1/72 inch)